# Modifying a rotary ceiling fan dial so it can be operated by touch

Tags: physical

My ceiling fans are controlled by wall dials. The dial has 5 positions - `off,1,2,3,4` - and spins between them without stopping (meaning you can turn from `off` to both `1` and `4` directly, the rotation is never blocked). This has the usability issues that I must look at the dial when trying to adjust/turn off the fan, which is inconvenient, especially at night.

I've considered sticking some indicator (a small screw?) to the `off` position. But that doesn't remind me which way is `1` and which is `4`.

How can I modify this dial so I can operate it intuitively by touch alone? Note that I don't want to replace it completely, just modify the existing dial somehow.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, surely 1 screw to indicate what the active position is is enough? Or just a marker pen to draw the line. Surely whatever is the top most value is the one that is applied right?

Comment: Buy one of those sensing lights and fit it close to the control.  Quick and cheap !

Comment: @musefan: Yes, top is the active state. However, I want to somehow know, *by touch*, that right=1 and left=4.

Comment: @PhillipW: Yes, but the writing is quite small, and I'll need to find my glasses or squint from really close, which is suboptimal. That's why I'm striving for a touch-only solution.

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem now. To be honest I think you are better off just remembering which side of the screw is 1 and which side is 4. "When screw is at top (off), CLOCKWISE means increasing from 1-4"

Comment: @musefan: Remembering = bad UX design, especially during nighttime, or when your significant other tries to operate it. That's why I'm looking for an all-touch, no-remembering solution.

Comment: Well, even with a touch system, you still need to remember what each "thing" represents anyway. I.e. you need to remember that the screw = off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to be able to spin it one way until it stops in the off position so you don't have to look.

I'm not sure how the dial is constructed and your DIY abilities but I'd try something like this.

Add a stud (screw or dowel for example) to the side of the dial sticking outward. Then add another pin into the backing plate of the dial so it points towards you in such a position that it prevents the dial (with side pin) rotating continuously. If you position both pins in the right place you have the desired outcome.

Added by OP - Illustration:

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Excellent idea, accepted. I'll report if&when I try it - for now, I just taped something to the `off` position.

Comment: @Jonathan: How are you going to remember which way to turn it?

Comment: @musefan: It will only turn one way, see illustration I added to this answer

Comment: I think that's a really neat solution - it marks both the zero position and indicates which way to turn.

Answer (score 1):

I would fix it with a thick semi-circle transparent vinyl adhesive. The edge of the sticker indicates which way to move the dial:

[image]

Edit after the comment:

If you put the sticker just on the `off` state, you are at the same situation as in your question with the screw. The half circle shows:

- Relief in the center (relief off to the left/relief on to the right) = OFF position
- Way to the relief ON (CCW) = higher velocity
- Way to the relief OFF (CW) = lower velocity

Comment: Interesting idea (and cool photo-edit!) However, how would feeling the `off`-`2.5` line tell me which way is off? Maybe it's better to put the adhesive to only cover the `off` state?

Comment: Answer updated .-

Answer (score 1):

The screw you propose (or drop of glue, or adhesive googly-eye) secured to the <kbd>OFF</kbd> position should help you memorize it by touch pretty quick, once you're no longer relying on your sight to inform you.

I think the issue is the mental model associated with turning this knob. Do not think of it as a water valve (where counter-clockwise means more), but instead **think of it as a volume knob**, where counter-clockwise means less. The curious exception to this is that you can wrap around to <kbd>4</kbd> from <kbd>OFF</kbd>, but I think that will become less of an issue as you memorize the position of <kbd>OFF</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to retain the current dial, I have seen some dials have a constraint, that If you rotate clockwise to the max it achieves max speed and u can turn it off by rotating ant-clockwise. Just like opening and closing the water tap.

Another Idea is that, some pedestal fans have radio buttons on them so u can only press one at a time from Zero (Off) to 3 (Fastest)

Maybe you could incorporate this approach for the ceiling fan as well

[image]

Comment: There are any number of designs I could use. My question is how to modify the existing dial, not buy/manufacture another control - I'll clarify that in the OP.